# Prevent expression from evaluation in function when using `ToString `

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, hold

I defined function `fhold`

```
Clear[fhold]
SetAttributes[fhold, HoldAll]
fhold[para_List] := ToString[para];
```

What I want is that when evaluate the following

```
k0 = 0.4 \[Pi];
fhold[{1, k0}]
```

I want it to give

```
"{1,0.4π}"
```

But it won't, it gives

```
"{1, 1.25664}"
```

Using `HoldForm` will not work either,

```
fhold[para_List] := ToString[HoldForm@para];
```

will give

```
"{1, k0}"
```

So how to define `fhold` to get "{1,0.4π}"?

Comment: It is too late. By the time `fhold` sees `k0`, `k0` has already evaluated to `1.25664`. You can't work back from this; the solution is to have e.g. `k0 = HoldForm[0.4 \[Pi]]`. Then, `fhold` works as it is.

Comment: I suppose using rational coefficients is out of the question?

Comment: @OleksandrR. The problem is that the function I really works with doing numerical calculation. If I supplied it with HoldForm[k0], calculation won't be done. The reason I want to get string "{1,0.4π}" is that I have lines in the function to `DumpSave` the result into a file, and I use "{1,0.4π}" in the file name

Comment: @OleksandrR. and also `k0` is a key variable, and its value is used in many other place, so I assign the value specifically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You at least have to provide `k0` with a delayed definition, otherwise you've fallen at the first hurdle, since the original input will already have been lost. This will give you a fighting chance:

```
k0 := 0.4 π;
```

Now, we need to work with the (unevaluated) ownvalues of this symbol, rather than allowing its definition ever to evaluate. Since we don't know what might be contained within the list (symbols or otherwise), we need rules to deal with all possibilities rather than just passing them indiscriminately to `OwnValues`:

```
ClearAll[myOwnValues];
SetAttributes[myOwnValues, HoldAll];
myOwnValues[lst_List] := myOwnValues /@ Unevaluated[lst];
myOwnValues[sym_Symbol] := OwnValues[sym];
myOwnValues[_] := {};
```

Now,

```
Flatten@myOwnValues[{1, k0}]
(* -> {HoldPattern[k0] :> 0.4 π} *)
```

which is a reasonable start.

Modifying your `fhold` to use this is straightforward:

```
ClearAll[fhold];
SetAttributes[fhold, HoldAll];
fhold[para_List] := ToString[HoldForm[para] /. Flatten@myOwnValues[para]];
```

And,

```
fhold[{1, k0}]
(* -> "{1, 0.4 Pi}" *)
```

as desired.

If you insist on `π` instead of `Pi`, you will need to specify `ToString[..., StandardForm]` rather than the default second argument of `OutputForm`. Or, remove `ToString` entirely and just leave `HoldForm` as the wrapper for this output.